Default font for composing messages on Apple Mail ( MacOS Sonoma )
How do I change the default font for composing messages in Apple Mail on MacOS 14 ?

In Mail -> Settings You can set default fonts, but that does not affect the font when composing messages.

In Mail -> Settings -> Composing there is no option to set the font.

The Default font in the "Compose" pane is Helvetica 12.  That can be changed, but only for the one message. Compose a new message and it goes back to Helvetica 12.

I've explored ~/Library/Preferences for a plist file that I could perhaps edit, but I'm not finding anything obvious for Apple Mail.


Is there anyway to change the default font for composing messages ?

Mail Settings → Fonts & Colours → Message font.
Tested that this sets the font for composed messages and for incoming messages where not overridden by the message.

I wonder now if I was not confused by an annoying bug.  When I respond to a message, the font that is shown is the one I set in Settings -> Fonts & Colors -> Message Font.     When I go to compose a new message, the font shows as Helvetica 12 on top of the "compose" pane, no matter what font I set in Settings. However when I start to type though the correct font is used and displayed. I'm using MacOS 14.5. Is that what you tested on ?
